# Compressing 'public' identifiers

Tags: javascript, google-closure-compiler

Before compiler:

```
function Foo(){
    this.init = function(){
        var bar = new Bar();
        bar.init();
    };
}

function Bar(){
    this.init = function(){
        console.log('Hello');
    };
}

$(window).load(function(){
    var foo;
    foo = new Foo();
    foo.init();
});
```

After running closure compiler and formatting:

```
function Foo(){
    this.init=function(){
        (new Bar).init()
        }
    }

function Bar(){
    this.init=function(){
        console.log("Hello")
        }
    }

$(window).load(function(){
    (new Foo).init()
    });
```

How can I get the compiler to compress the 'init' identifier, so we have e.g. 'a' instead of 'init' ?

Comment: What do you mean by "compress"?

Comment: Make them non-global? (I guess that's what you mean by "public")

Comment: Your whole script boils down to `$(window).load(console.log.bind(console,"Hello"));` if you remove everything unnecessary. Is that what you want?

Comment: @Robert - I want all 'init' to be minified (to e.g. 'b' or 'c' etc)

Comment: Advanced optimizations mode will rename methods.

Comment: @Bergi - no, please read the question (last line)

Comment: @Stevensson Using advanced optimizations is exactly what you want, but make sure you read "[What to Watch Out for When Using ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#dangers)" from Closure's documentation. For example, if you are writing a library or module, someone else may want to use your `init` function, so you'll need to know how to *prevent* it from being renamed.

Comment: @apsillers Thank you, I am reading it now

Answer (score 2):

As others have suggested, you must enabled ADVANCED_OPTIMIZATIONS, as documented [here](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3).

One caveat, even with advanced compilation, some properties will not be renamed - in the [FAQ](https://code.google.com/p/closure-compiler/wiki/FAQ#How_do_I_write_an_externs_file?) this is covered in detail

Answer (score -2):

You don't want to do that. `init` is a public method. Code that invokes `init` has an expectation for it to be named as such. Imagine if you wanted to use a compressed version of jQuery but all of the method names were minified. "What's the short name for .each()?" It can certainly be done, but it is counter productive and voids reliability of your code.

As another brief anecdote, the Google Maps JavaScript API is minified. Properties of the LatLng object were minified to something like $a and $b. I referenced these properties directly to access the latitude and longitude values. Then Google rebuilt the file and the property names changed to something else! Instead of referencing the minified properties, I used the API documentation to find *public methods* that had a consistent, expected name: getLatitude() and getLongitude(). These methods referenced the internal properties by their minified names and simply returned their values. Had the method names been included in minification, I'd be back to the original problem.

Comment: If you compile all of your code at once, Closure-compiler can rename every reference to a method, variable or property correctly and thus avoid breaking references.

Comment: @ChadKillingsworth that's exactly the point; you're restricting the code that can implement your minified methods to code that is available at compile time. This is exactly why aggressive minification can be harmful, as upvoted in the question comments. https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#dangers

Comment: If "init" is so important that it needs to be preserved, you can export the symbol. Closure docs [cover this in detail](https://developers.google.com/closure/compiler/docs/api-tutorial3#export)